# Формат ico обязателен?

Tags: html, расширения, icon

Обязательно ли фавиконки сохранять в формат ico? Браузер и png понимает (по крайней мере Chrome)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PNG, как формат иконки понимается всеми "нормальными" браузерами: MF, GH, Opera, Safari; а вот IE не воспринимает этот формат для иконки сайта.

**P.S**

IE вообще очень много чего воспринимает не так, как нормальные браузеры. Ведь все знают, что IE по сути - мертвец...даже не знаю, зачем Microsoft продолжает его рекламировать...

Comment: Не смотря на то, что IE какашкО - это первый браузер (на основе его появились все остальные, очень много вещей MS внедряли первыми) + это до сих пор один из самых популярных браузеров в мире (собственно - с чего MS'у на него забивать?)

К тому-же 10ый IE будет абсолютно нормальным браузером (за редкими исключениями, например webgl), так что я, мягко говоря, не согласен с тем, что IE мертвец, не думайте что в MS работают идиоты.

PS: не являюсь приверженцем MS (видно из авы :D), тем более не являюсь приверженцем IE (IE must die, но он не умрет т.к. за ним стоят большие деньги и умные люди)

Comment: @AlexWindHope, согласен с вами...IE и правда не умрет, но Microsoft слишком уж перенапичкала его своими реализациями существующих технологий, а точнее их модификациями. Так, например, если в нормальных браузерах все связанное с кодировкой работает хорошо, то для IE придется повозиться. Еще я слыхал, что обработка JS-сценариев в IE тоже специфичная. Но тем не менее если создавать проект чисто для IE, то это покажется очень удобным, но в таком случае про кроссбраузерность можно и не зарекаться...

Comment: Если быть максимально точным - это остальные браузеры понаделывали "своих" реализаций (IE же умел делать очень многие вещи еще **до существования стандартов**). А вопросы кодировок и т.д. легко объясняются тем, что IE, просто напросто, старичок (если рассматривать ie7-).

@Asen - были времена когда под другие браузеры **вообще** не было смысла что-либо писать, те времена прошли, IE остался, собственно в чем тут вина MS? (в данном случае ее попросту нет)

Ну а далее MS'у нужно было перестраиваться под w3c, что они, как могли, собственно, и делали...

Comment: IE - первый браузер? я почему то думал, что Netscape, который сейчас мозилой называется, а ие, по истории, стал популярным(это не означает, что лучшим), только изза того что мс встроила его в виндовс, отбив желание у домохозяек ставить что-то другое.

Comment: @Gorets - где я писал что это лучший браузер?

Когда я писал первый браузер я подразумевал первый масштабно используемый браузер, еще вопросы будут?

Comment: Ну, в 1996 на всех имеющих доступ к Интернет компьютерах моего города был установлен именно Netscape второй и третьей версии, ну да ладно :) 

Жесткая конкурентная борьба IE и NC в конце 90-х привела к появлению большого количества нестандартных фич типа тэга margin. Фавиконки тоже в Microsoft придумали. Ну или по крайней мере первыми реализовали.

Насчет заявлений о будущей полной совместимости IE со стандартами - возможно, если полностью движок перепишут. Одно время Балмер выдал фразу, что рассматривается вариант использовать WebKit. Забыл тогда глянуть на календарь - не первое ли апреля :)

Answer (score 1):

Можно написать для нормальных браузеров:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/fav.png" />
```

А для Micro$oft IE:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="/fav.ico" />
```

Или вообще забить на M$IE.

Comment: Это вообще бессмысленно. Если уже сделал ico, То смысл еще png приделывать?